# Reopen a completed project on Active Collab

Tags: activecollab

How can I run the reopen project that is found on completed projects in active collab (the URL, and or data I need to post)?

I already have new project, complete project, and a slew of other commands implemented, so I have the API up and running.

I also tested this in PUT and POST to no avail:
**/projects/ID DATA-> "is_completed": false**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to open a completed project, you'd need to hit dedicated API endpoint for that which is

`api/v1/open/project/{projectId}` => where you'll replace {projectId} with your projectId ID.

Keep in mind that the method is `PUT`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! That worked perfectly for me, and I am up and running.